# Can't do dualboot with Windows 10, options missing

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

Tried to install elementary OS the same way I used to before - Leave free space at the time of Windows installation and then just split it up during elementary OS installation. But now there's no options for it, at the begging in doesn't even offer side by side install (just option to delete Windows 10). Option of installation called "Something Else" gives me partition but doesn't allow me to split up "unusable" partition (+ and - buttons are greyed out). Why is it unusable?

Am I missing something?

Link to picture of this situation - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi6Vn.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're booting elementary OS in BIOS/MBR/Legacy mode, which allows only up to 4 primary partitions per disk drive. Booting in EFI/UEFI will allow you to install both OSes in UEFI mode, but you need to recreate the disk's partition table and use the GPT one for this to work, because GPT or GUID Partition Table supports up to 128 primary partitions.If Windows is installed in Legacy mode, you'll have to reinstall both OSes. If your machine doesn't support UEFI/EFI, you'll have to fit in 4 parts max. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate! This seems to make sense. Backing everything up gonna take some time and then I'll try to see if any of the data preserving methods of conversion to GPT work.